# How to set relative path for icons in Windows

Tags: windows, icons

We are trying to disribute Pen Drives for a certain cause and we have some folders for which we want to display our own custom icons.

The .ico files are present on the pen-drive itself. We are trying the old-school method for changing the icons i.e. **Properties > Customize > Change Icon**

However, the problem is that on different systems, the *drive-letter changes* and *so does the path*. Due to this, the icons don't get displayed as we intend them to do.

Please suggest a way to set the path of the icons in such a way that they can be displayed on all systems regardless of the drive-letter of the usb-drive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Place a file called `desktop.ini` inside each folder and fill it with this content:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=..\Icons\my_resourceDLL.dll,XXX
```

Or:

```
IconResource=..\Icons\icon.ico,0
```

Where `XXX` is the icon number. `..\Icons` is a relative path, you can use your own dir name.

Comment: how to put the icon files with .ico extension in dll files?

Comment: Try googling for it or ask another SO question.

Comment: I've added an option for direct icon file,

Comment: The file should be a UTF-16 file. Just copy a desktop.ini from your windows installation and edit it. Right click on a folder and coose customize to create  such a file. Works in Win8.1 too. Sometimes windows caches the icon, so wait a while or reboot.

Comment: Is it possible, that this is not working for SMB-shares which is hosted on Linux computer? I setup the desktop.ini on my windows computer and try to see the file tree in windows. My desktop.ini is not hidden and I dont see my custom icon :(

Comment: And how should the .url `IconFile=` value look in this case ? also, to see the change, you should End/Restart the explorer.exe/"Windows Explorer" process, preferably to have `Ribbon \ Options \ "Launch folder windows in a separate process"` on .